# How do I reduce the gap between the icons on the system tray?

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel

I'd like to reduce the spacing between the icons in the system tray on the top right, the spacing seems out of place with the rest of the design and it's melting my brain a little.  I've hunted on here and google and found a fix which involves changing the 'padding' in the app.css file but it's not working for me. Is the system using a different .css maybe? Does anyone know any other workarounds for this?

Answer (score 2):

Padding doesn't work anymore, for some reason, on Wingpanel 2.2.6.
There is however a solution and you can find it here:

https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1#issuecomment-546731215

Big thanks to Marcus André (https://github.com/marcussacana) who made this fix.

Answer (score 2):

This method taken from [this comment on Github](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1#issuecomment-560757367) worked for me on 5.1 Hera:

1. Create a `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file
2. Insert the below contents

```
/* source: https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1 */
.composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

3. Reboot your system

The other methods above didn't work for me in Hera, as `.composited-indicator` no longer exists within `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`. This is probably a better method anyway, because `~/.config` user config, and so is less likely to be reverted when Wingpanel or the theme is updated in the future.

Comment: Do you know how to reduce the indicator icon size?